# How to get R console output as log file in Azure

Tags: r, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring

I hosted an R shiny application in the Azure portal (as an app service using docker image), due to some reason the tool is getting crashed hence I want to see the R output log in Azure portal to understand what is happening in the azure portal

I have added STDOUT & STDERR messages in my R code to print log files

when I try to get the logs (in azure cloud shell) using
`az container logs --resource-group myResourceGroup --name mycontainer1`

I'm not able to get any STDOUT or STDERR messages in the log file

help me to get the actual R console output

Note: I want to see only the R console outputs, 
In the container log, I'm getting only app background logs

thanks in advance

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, the logs for the image is defined yourself. See more [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-get-logs) to understand it.

For the ACI, you can use the command `az container logs` and `az container attach` to get the logs outside the containers. Or just go inside the containers to view the logs yourself.

For the Web App, you can also use the command [`az webapp logs show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/log?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-log-show) and [`az webapp logs tail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/log?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-log-tail) to view the logs. And the Azure portal, in the container setting, also shows the logs.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i already tried using az container logs but i'm getting only container log info (like container is building , ready to serve requests) i want to see the R studio output

Comment: @Nandan I have no experience on R. But you can output the message into the standard IO yourself in R code.

Comment: I have added Stdout messages in my R code but when I check azure web app logs I'm not getting those stdout messages, I'm getting only the "container is ready to serve request message "                                                                     **example:** 2020-05-19T18:42:55.211Z INFO  - Container webappname_0_454e9521 for site <webappname> initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.

Answer (score 0):

I got the logs by hosting the docker image as a container instance instead of web app [Azure portal Docker container instance sample view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIFXf.jpg) .

The R shiny logs listed in var/logs/shiny folder